# Docker - Laravel - Not able to set it up

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I am simply unable to get my laravel app up and running on nginx reverse proxy on digital ocean using docker. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am getting 502 or 500 errors.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM php:7.2.2-fpm

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

CMD php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

and my docker-compose.yml file is

```
version: "3"

services:
  # App php-fpm service
  app:
    build: ./
    container_name: livechats_app
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: livechats.mikolaj.dk
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 8000
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: livechats.mikolaj.dk
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: mikoo1991@yahoo.com
```

Comment: Maybe you have to expose your port before executing your command in the dockerfile

Comment: i tried that, now im getting 502 error...

Comment: now im seeing the page, but its empty...

Answer (score 0):

Exposing a port, doesn't bind it to the host, it only share with other services inside docker network

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2.2-fpm

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8000
CMD php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8000
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  # App php-fpm service
  app:
    build: ./
    container_name: livechats_app
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: livechats.mikolaj.dk
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 8000
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: livechats.mikolaj.dk
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: mikoo1991@yahoo.com
```